Graylog CloudWatch setup not working - IAM issues
I setup a Graylog cluster with 5.2.6 and OpenSearch 2.1.13 as well as MongoDB in my AWS Cloud on an EC2 t3.large instance. Everything is working fine and the containers can communicate with each other. Now I am trying to setup the CloudWatch/Kinesis data input but it doesn't seem to work.
I am connecting to my EC2 instance via Session Manager and have setup the SSM Role for it successfully. I added the policy as stated in the Graylog docs
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "GraylogKinesisSetup",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
        "dynamodb:CreateTable",
        "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
        "dynamodb:GetItem",
        "dynamodb:PutItem",
        "dynamodb:Scan",
        "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
        "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
        "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
        "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancerAttributes",
        "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
        "iam:CreateRole",
        "iam:GetRole",
        "iam:PassRole",
        "iam:PutRolePolicy",
        "kinesis:CreateStream",
        "kinesis:DescribeStream",
        "kinesis:GetRecords",
        "kinesis:GetShardIterator",
        "kinesis:ListShards",
        "kinesis:ListStreams",
        "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
        "logs:PutSubscriptionFilter"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}

Then I've created a role with STS privileges and attached it to that role. Also attached this policy to the SSM role I've created and added each other in their trusted relationships. Everytime I am trying to setup the input I am getting this error:
ERROR
Also, the upper role stays the same. Probably, because that's the role that creates the connection to the instance on which Graylog is running and also executes the commands.
I've tried adding different Principles to the roles and gave them more rights than they need, also for all ressources and everything. I've setup a role "Graylog-Cloudwatch_role" with STS privileges and the Kinesis/CloudWatch recommended policies from the Graylog docs. I've literally tried everything but I don't understand what the issue is. Also, I am not very familiar with AWS in general. I appreciate every help I can get. I hope I've provided enough information
